# Weird Error with $_FILES

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a normal form

```
<form action="myfile.php" method="post" enctype="mulitpart/form-data">
  ...
  <input type="file" class="fileupload" name="images[1]">
</form>
```

and on the php side i am checking in `$_FILES` but i am getting nothing, but `$_REQUEST` (which i never use) can see the variable. I have been posting forms with files for years but never come across this error, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have an index in the name?

Comment: i have 5 images that I am processing, in a PHP loop the index specifies the order to display on the view page

Comment: try name="images[]" instead of name="images[1]"... it may help you.

Comment: `$_REQUEST` can see *which* variable?

Comment: @Rukmi Patel really?!?! that isn't going to help! @Phil it can see all forms variables including the `images` array

Comment: @Lizard I'm noticing a trend here, check your question title ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
enctype="mulitpart/form-data" => enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Alas! It was a spelling mistake

Comment: Boom!!! what a rookie mistake!

Comment: i must have looked over that like 1000 times

Comment: Hehe, *mulitpart*. Business form in the front, party form in the back :)